# Icons doesn't display accordingly on web page

Tags: html, css

I'm consulting a web page where there are some icons like those in the image below (FIG.1); I was trying to copy the code to get these icons, and when I try to run it on my html page I get FIG.2.

Why does this happen?

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="at-share-btn-elements">
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-facebook" style="background-color: rgb(59, 89, 152); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Facebook</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-facebook-1" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-facebook">
                    <title id="at-svg-facebook-1">Facebook</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M22 5.16c-.406-.054-1.806-.16-3.43-.16-3.4 0-5.733 1.825-5.733 5.17v2.882H9v3.913h3.837V27h4.604V16.965h3.823l.587-3.913h-4.41v-2.5c0-1.123.347-1.903 2.198-1.903H22V5.16z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-twitter" style="background-color: rgb(29, 161, 242); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Twitter</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-twitter-2" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-twitter">
                    <title id="at-svg-twitter-2">Twitter</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M27.996 10.116c-.81.36-1.68.602-2.592.71a4.526 4.526 0 0 0 1.984-2.496 9.037 9.037 0 0 1-2.866 1.095 4.513 4.513 0 0 0-7.69 4.116 12.81 12.81 0 0 1-9.3-4.715 4.49 4.49 0 0 0-.612 2.27 4.51 4.51 0 0 0 2.008 3.755 4.495 4.495 0 0 1-2.044-.564v.057a4.515 4.515 0 0 0 3.62 4.425 4.52 4.52 0 0 1-2.04.077 4.517 4.517 0 0 0 4.217 3.134 9.055 9.055 0 0 1-5.604 1.93A9.18 9.18 0 0 1 6 23.85a12.773 12.773 0 0 0 6.918 2.027c8.3 0 12.84-6.876 12.84-12.84 0-.195-.005-.39-.014-.583a9.172 9.172 0 0 0 2.252-2.336" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-whatsapp" style="background-color: rgb(77, 194, 71); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to WhatsApp</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-whatsapp-3" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-whatsapp">
                    <title id="at-svg-whatsapp-3">WhatsApp</title>
                    <g><path d="M19.11 17.205c-.372 0-1.088 1.39-1.518 1.39a.63.63 0 0 1-.315-.1c-.802-.402-1.504-.817-2.163-1.447-.545-.516-1.146-1.29-1.46-1.963a.426.426 0 0 1-.073-.215c0-.33.99-.945.99-1.49 0-.143-.73-2.09-.832-2.335-.143-.372-.214-.487-.6-.487-.187 0-.36-.043-.53-.043-.302 0-.53.115-.746.315-.688.645-1.032 1.318-1.06 2.264v.114c-.015.99.472 1.977 1.017 2.78 1.23 1.82 2.506 3.41 4.554 4.34.616.287 2.035.888 2.722.888.817 0 2.15-.515 2.478-1.318.13-.33.244-.73.244-1.088 0-.058 0-.144-.03-.215-.1-.172-2.434-1.39-2.678-1.39zm-2.908 7.593c-1.747 0-3.48-.53-4.942-1.49L7.793 24.41l1.132-3.337a8.955 8.955 0 0 1-1.72-5.272c0-4.955 4.04-8.995 8.997-8.995S25.2 10.845 25.2 15.8c0 4.958-4.04 8.998-8.998 8.998zm0-19.798c-5.96 0-10.8 4.842-10.8 10.8 0 1.964.53 3.898 1.546 5.574L5 27.176l5.974-1.92a10.807 10.807 0 0 0 16.03-9.455c0-5.958-4.842-10.8-10.802-10.8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-pinterest_share" style="background-color: rgb(203, 32, 39); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Pinterest</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-pinterest_share-4" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-pinterest_share">
                    <title id="at-svg-pinterest_share-4">Pinterest</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M7 13.252c0 1.81.772 4.45 2.895 5.045.074.014.178.04.252.04.49 0 .772-1.27.772-1.63 0-.428-1.174-1.34-1.174-3.123 0-3.705 3.028-6.33 6.947-6.33 3.37 0 5.863 1.782 5.863 5.058 0 2.446-1.054 7.035-4.468 7.035-1.232 0-2.286-.83-2.286-2.018 0-1.742 1.307-3.43 1.307-5.225 0-1.092-.67-1.977-1.916-1.977-1.692 0-2.732 1.77-2.732 3.165 0 .774.104 1.63.476 2.336-.683 2.736-2.08 6.814-2.08 9.633 0 .87.135 1.728.224 2.6l.134.137.207-.07c2.494-3.178 2.405-3.8 3.533-7.96.61 1.077 2.182 1.658 3.43 1.658 5.254 0 7.614-4.77 7.614-9.067C26 7.987 21.755 5 17.094 5 12.017 5 7 8.15 7 13.252z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-link" style="background-color: rgb(23, 139, 244); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Copy Link</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-link-5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-link">
                    <title id="at-svg-link-5">Copy Link</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M23.476 20.663c0-.324-.114-.6-.34-.825l-2.524-2.524a1.124 1.124 0 0 0-.826-.34c-.34 0-.63.13-.873.388.024.024.1.1.23.225s.217.212.26.26c.046.05.106.126.183.23a.976.976 0 0 1 .2.644c0 .325-.113.6-.34.827-.226.226-.5.34-.825.34-.12 0-.23-.015-.332-.043a.976.976 0 0 1-.31-.158 2.89 2.89 0 0 1-.23-.182 7.506 7.506 0 0 1-.26-.26l-.226-.23c-.267.25-.4.545-.4.885 0 .322.113.597.34.824l2.5 2.512c.218.218.493.328.825.328.323 0 .598-.106.825-.316l1.784-1.772a1.11 1.11 0 0 0 .34-.813zm-8.532-8.556c0-.323-.113-.598-.34-.825l-2.5-2.512a1.124 1.124 0 0 0-.825-.34c-.316 0-.59.11-.826.328L8.67 10.53a1.11 1.11 0 0 0-.34.813c0 .323.113.598.34.825l2.524 2.524c.22.22.494.328.825.328.34 0 .63-.126.873-.376-.024-.025-.1-.1-.23-.225a7.506 7.506 0 0 1-.26-.262 2.89 2.89 0 0 1-.183-.23.976.976 0 0 1-.2-.644c0-.323.113-.598.34-.825.226-.227.5-.34.824-.34a.976.976 0 0 1 .643.2c.106.077.183.137.23.182.05.044.137.13.262.26s.2.207.224.23c.267-.25.4-.545.4-.885zm10.862 8.556c0 .97-.344 1.792-1.032 2.464L22.99 24.9c-.67.67-1.492 1.006-2.463 1.006-.98 0-1.805-.344-2.476-1.032l-2.5-2.512c-.67-.67-1.006-1.493-1.006-2.463 0-.997.356-1.842 1.068-2.538l-1.068-1.068c-.696.712-1.538 1.068-2.525 1.068-.97 0-1.797-.34-2.476-1.02L7.02 13.82C6.34 13.138 6 12.314 6 11.343c0-.97.344-1.792 1.032-2.464l1.784-1.773c.67-.67 1.492-1.007 2.463-1.007.978 0 1.803.344 2.475 1.032l2.5 2.512c.67.67 1.007 1.492 1.007 2.463 0 .995-.356 1.84-1.068 2.537l1.068 1.068c.696-.712 1.537-1.068 2.524-1.068.97 0 1.797.34 2.476 1.02l2.524 2.523c.68.68 1.02 1.505 1.02 2.476z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-compact" style="background-color: rgb(255, 101, 80); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Più...</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-addthis-6" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-addthis">
                    <title id="at-svg-addthis-6">AddThis</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M18 14V8h-4v6H8v4h6v6h4v-6h6v-4h-6z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

It is the first time I have done such a thing, I am a beginner in this.

Comment: There is almost certainly additional CSS on the page you copied this from. You have things like the `class` attribute on some of these tags but without the original CSS, they won't be styled/changed.

Comment: how do i understand the corresponding css?

Comment: I would suggest learning more about CSS before trying to ... liberate ... other people's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lot of css missing. I have added a few line of CSS so that you can see what is missing;

```css
.at-share-btn-elements{
display: flex;
gap: 1px;
}
.at4-visually-hidden{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="at-share-btn-elements">
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-facebook" style="background-color: rgb(59, 89, 152); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Facebook</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-facebook-1" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-facebook">
                    <title id="at-svg-facebook-1">Facebook</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M22 5.16c-.406-.054-1.806-.16-3.43-.16-3.4 0-5.733 1.825-5.733 5.17v2.882H9v3.913h3.837V27h4.604V16.965h3.823l.587-3.913h-4.41v-2.5c0-1.123.347-1.903 2.198-1.903H22V5.16z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-twitter" style="background-color: rgb(29, 161, 242); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Twitter</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-twitter-2" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-twitter">
                    <title id="at-svg-twitter-2">Twitter</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M27.996 10.116c-.81.36-1.68.602-2.592.71a4.526 4.526 0 0 0 1.984-2.496 9.037 9.037 0 0 1-2.866 1.095 4.513 4.513 0 0 0-7.69 4.116 12.81 12.81 0 0 1-9.3-4.715 4.49 4.49 0 0 0-.612 2.27 4.51 4.51 0 0 0 2.008 3.755 4.495 4.495 0 0 1-2.044-.564v.057a4.515 4.515 0 0 0 3.62 4.425 4.52 4.52 0 0 1-2.04.077 4.517 4.517 0 0 0 4.217 3.134 9.055 9.055 0 0 1-5.604 1.93A9.18 9.18 0 0 1 6 23.85a12.773 12.773 0 0 0 6.918 2.027c8.3 0 12.84-6.876 12.84-12.84 0-.195-.005-.39-.014-.583a9.172 9.172 0 0 0 2.252-2.336" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-whatsapp" style="background-color: rgb(77, 194, 71); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to WhatsApp</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-whatsapp-3" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-whatsapp">
                    <title id="at-svg-whatsapp-3">WhatsApp</title>
                    <g><path d="M19.11 17.205c-.372 0-1.088 1.39-1.518 1.39a.63.63 0 0 1-.315-.1c-.802-.402-1.504-.817-2.163-1.447-.545-.516-1.146-1.29-1.46-1.963a.426.426 0 0 1-.073-.215c0-.33.99-.945.99-1.49 0-.143-.73-2.09-.832-2.335-.143-.372-.214-.487-.6-.487-.187 0-.36-.043-.53-.043-.302 0-.53.115-.746.315-.688.645-1.032 1.318-1.06 2.264v.114c-.015.99.472 1.977 1.017 2.78 1.23 1.82 2.506 3.41 4.554 4.34.616.287 2.035.888 2.722.888.817 0 2.15-.515 2.478-1.318.13-.33.244-.73.244-1.088 0-.058 0-.144-.03-.215-.1-.172-2.434-1.39-2.678-1.39zm-2.908 7.593c-1.747 0-3.48-.53-4.942-1.49L7.793 24.41l1.132-3.337a8.955 8.955 0 0 1-1.72-5.272c0-4.955 4.04-8.995 8.997-8.995S25.2 10.845 25.2 15.8c0 4.958-4.04 8.998-8.998 8.998zm0-19.798c-5.96 0-10.8 4.842-10.8 10.8 0 1.964.53 3.898 1.546 5.574L5 27.176l5.974-1.92a10.807 10.807 0 0 0 16.03-9.455c0-5.958-4.842-10.8-10.802-10.8z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-pinterest_share" style="background-color: rgb(203, 32, 39); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Pinterest</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-pinterest_share-4" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-pinterest_share">
                    <title id="at-svg-pinterest_share-4">Pinterest</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M7 13.252c0 1.81.772 4.45 2.895 5.045.074.014.178.04.252.04.49 0 .772-1.27.772-1.63 0-.428-1.174-1.34-1.174-3.123 0-3.705 3.028-6.33 6.947-6.33 3.37 0 5.863 1.782 5.863 5.058 0 2.446-1.054 7.035-4.468 7.035-1.232 0-2.286-.83-2.286-2.018 0-1.742 1.307-3.43 1.307-5.225 0-1.092-.67-1.977-1.916-1.977-1.692 0-2.732 1.77-2.732 3.165 0 .774.104 1.63.476 2.336-.683 2.736-2.08 6.814-2.08 9.633 0 .87.135 1.728.224 2.6l.134.137.207-.07c2.494-3.178 2.405-3.8 3.533-7.96.61 1.077 2.182 1.658 3.43 1.658 5.254 0 7.614-4.77 7.614-9.067C26 7.987 21.755 5 17.094 5 12.017 5 7 8.15 7 13.252z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-link" style="background-color: rgb(23, 139, 244); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Copy Link</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-link-5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-link">
                    <title id="at-svg-link-5">Copy Link</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M23.476 20.663c0-.324-.114-.6-.34-.825l-2.524-2.524a1.124 1.124 0 0 0-.826-.34c-.34 0-.63.13-.873.388.024.024.1.1.23.225s.217.212.26.26c.046.05.106.126.183.23a.976.976 0 0 1 .2.644c0 .325-.113.6-.34.827-.226.226-.5.34-.825.34-.12 0-.23-.015-.332-.043a.976.976 0 0 1-.31-.158 2.89 2.89 0 0 1-.23-.182 7.506 7.506 0 0 1-.26-.26l-.226-.23c-.267.25-.4.545-.4.885 0 .322.113.597.34.824l2.5 2.512c.218.218.493.328.825.328.323 0 .598-.106.825-.316l1.784-1.772a1.11 1.11 0 0 0 .34-.813zm-8.532-8.556c0-.323-.113-.598-.34-.825l-2.5-2.512a1.124 1.124 0 0 0-.825-.34c-.316 0-.59.11-.826.328L8.67 10.53a1.11 1.11 0 0 0-.34.813c0 .323.113.598.34.825l2.524 2.524c.22.22.494.328.825.328.34 0 .63-.126.873-.376-.024-.025-.1-.1-.23-.225a7.506 7.506 0 0 1-.26-.262 2.89 2.89 0 0 1-.183-.23.976.976 0 0 1-.2-.644c0-.323.113-.598.34-.825.226-.227.5-.34.824-.34a.976.976 0 0 1 .643.2c.106.077.183.137.23.182.05.044.137.13.262.26s.2.207.224.23c.267-.25.4-.545.4-.885zm10.862 8.556c0 .97-.344 1.792-1.032 2.464L22.99 24.9c-.67.67-1.492 1.006-2.463 1.006-.98 0-1.805-.344-2.476-1.032l-2.5-2.512c-.67-.67-1.006-1.493-1.006-2.463 0-.997.356-1.842 1.068-2.538l-1.068-1.068c-.696.712-1.538 1.068-2.525 1.068-.97 0-1.797-.34-2.476-1.02L7.02 13.82C6.34 13.138 6 12.314 6 11.343c0-.97.344-1.792 1.032-2.464l1.784-1.773c.67-.67 1.492-1.007 2.463-1.007.978 0 1.803.344 2.475 1.032l2.5 2.512c.67.67 1.007 1.492 1.007 2.463 0 .995-.356 1.84-1.068 2.537l1.068 1.068c.696-.712 1.537-1.068 2.524-1.068.97 0 1.797.34 2.476 1.02l2.524 2.523c.68.68 1.02 1.505 1.02 2.476z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-compact" style="background-color: rgb(255, 101, 80); border-radius: 16px;">
            <span class="at4-visually-hidden">Share to Più...</span>
            <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" role="img" aria-labelledby="at-svg-addthis-6" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 20px; height: 20px;" class="at-icon at-icon-addthis">
                    <title id="at-svg-addthis-6">AddThis</title>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M18 14V8h-4v6H8v4h6v6h4v-6h6v-4h-6z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: These are just a few things. You have to center the icons, and as you can see in the snippet, the resultant circles are not radial enough. I would suggest learning some CSS before.

Comment: A thousand thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some other code missing, you definitely need the CSS page.

Comment: sorry and the <style> tag already present in the code does not concern the css?